# Encrypt ONE system directory?

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption

I dont want to encrypt my whole hard drive. But one app i ENJOY using stores my password in a not so secure way in the AppData folder. I would like to encrypt the folder. One note is the folder is inside my user/name directory. Maybe that will help or hinder the solution.

I am fine with encrypting all of AppData if necessary. However i prefer not to encrypt C:\Users\NAME\ since it is heavily used by many apps.

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\APPNAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the folder > General tab - Advanced... > Select Encrypt contents to secure data

That's encrypting with what's call [Encrypting File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System). On Windows 7, you'll need Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate edition.

Comment: darn. The box is grayed out. I have home premium.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to encrypt files marked as "system" in the supported NTFS encryption.
Are your files marked as such (see properties), I believe most stuff under AppData can be.
Some files are needed by the system and so can only be encrypted if you apply Bitlocker volume encryption. 
Otherwise (if not system files) you can encrypt the APPNAME folder by going to the properties (right click the folder) and mark the folder as encrypted there. 
Anyone logged in as you can see the data transparantly.

Comment: I believe acidzombie24 meant only that the directory is in a "system" place -- that is, not in the "user" area -- and not the "System" attribute.

Comment: Sure, but I had no Windows 7 system at hand to see whether these files would have that attribute or not. Some files under Appdata have, I know.

Answer (score 1):

I use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt data/app in a single folder. However, to use the folder, you need to open it with TrueCrypt each time, otherwise it will only look like a big text file.